# How to use Spring EL expressions in Thymeleaf `sec:authorize` attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a class used to store method security expressions.

```
public final class MethodSecurityExpressions {
    public static final String USER = "hasRole('USER')";
}
```

In controllers I've used it like this,

```
@PreAuthorize(MethodSecurityExpressions.USER)
@GetMapping("path/to/list")
public String list(Model model) {
    return "list";
}
```

In Thymeleaf templates I'm currently doing the following,

```
<ul sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')">
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

but I want to do something like this,

```
<ul sec:authorize="#{MethodSecurityExpressions.USER}">
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.8. I've read through the [JSP tag library documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/taglibs.html) and the [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html) and searched all over but not finding anything promising.

Does anyone know if this is possible, or know of a similar way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

The `sec:authorize` attribute evaluates a Spring Security Expression. This expression is in fact a Spring EL expression evaluated on a SpringSecurity-specific root object. Therefore an adequate solution could look like:

```
<div sec:authorize="${hasRole('#{T(org.example.MethodSecurityExpressions).USER)}'">
</div>
```

Class MethodSecurityExpression

```
package org.example;

public final class MethodSecurityExpressions {
    public static final String USER = "USER";
}
```

Sources:

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: I tried this using Spring Boot 2.4.4 with Thymeleaf 3.0.12 and it is not working. Is the expression exactly correct, because the brackets do not seem to be balanced in the expression?