# Spring boot Application with Thymeleaf. Using Constants to check hasAuthority

Tags: spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap, spring-security, thymeleaf

Defined constants in my class and using in UI to validate if user have the authority, show the menu to user else hide it. refer below code the way I implemented.

```
<li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('${T(com.sample.application.security.Privilege).ADMIN}')" class="nav-item" th:classappend="${template} == 'Home' ? 'active':''">
```

However, its not working as I expect. I was expecting thymeleaf to transform ${T(com.sample.application.security.Privilege).ADMIN} to ADMIN and verify it as hasAuthority('ADMIN') but thats not working. Is there any other way to do this validation in thymeleaf. Whats the best approach to get this implemented?

Update: Tried with assigning the constants to thymeleaf local variable as well. Didnt work either.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav" th:with="admin=${T(com.sample.application.security.Privilege).ADMINISTRATOR}, groupAdmin=${T(com.sample.application.security.Privilege).APPLICATION_GROUP_ADMIN}, basicUser=${T(com.sample.application.security.Privilege).APPLICATION_BASIC_USER}" >
                <li sec:authorize="hasAuthority(${basicUser}) OR hasAuthority(${admin})" class="nav-item" th:classappend="${template} == 'home' ? 'active':''">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/myApplication/User">Customer Home</a>
                </li>......</ul>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean exactly with "it is not working as I expect"?

Comment: Can you try with `hasAuthority(${T(come.sample.application.security.Privilege).ADMIN})` ? (So without the single quotes)

Comment: I was expecting thymeleaf to transform ${T(come.sample.application.security.Privilege).ADMIN} to ADMIN and verify it as hasAuthority('ADMIN') but thats not working.

Comment: Tried without single quotes as well and got an exception Expression [hasAuthority(${T(come.sample.application.security.Privilege).ADMIN})] @14: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'

Comment: Tried a few other options, but I can't seem to get it working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945701/how-to-use-spring-el-expressions-in-thymeleaf-secauthorize-attribute claims that it is possible, but the proposed solution did not work for me.

Comment: I have tried other options provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945701/how-to-use-spring-el-expressions-in-thymeleaf-secauthorize-attribute none of them worked for me either. Not sure I'm doing it correctly. 
1. `<div th:if"${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''Application_Admin'')')}">IM ADMIN</div>`

2. `<div th:if"${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority('${T(com.sample.application.security.Privilege).APPLICATION_ADMIN}')')}">I M GROUP ADMIN</div>`

Didnt work for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several ways. Below solution worked without any issue.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li sec:authorize="${hasAuthority(T(com.sample.application.security.Privilege).ADMINISTRATOR) OR hasAuthority(T(com.sample.application.security.Privilege).APPLICATION_GROUP_ADMIN)}" class="nav-item" th:classappend="${template} == 'home' ? 'active':''">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/myApplication/User">Customer Home</a>
</li>
```